# Why is storing secrets in android gradle recommended if it can be decompiled like hardcoded string?

Tags: android, build.gradle, reverse-engineering, decompiler

I'm trying to understand the benefits of storing secrets in Gradle properties when they're still exposed in decompiled code.
For example, let's say I store a secret key in `gradle.properties`:

```
API_KEY="Some Secret String"
```

Then, I referenced this key in build.gradle app defaultConfig section

```
buildConfigField("String", "GRADLE_KEY_PASSWORD", GRADLE_KEY_PASSWORD)
```

And I access it on my java class

```
String hiddenKey=BuildConfig.API_KEY;
```

but when I decompile the app with jadx, the secret key is exposed as a hardcoded string like this:

```
this.f1416x = "Some Secret String";
```

What is the benefit of doing this other than version control?

Comment: To make your API keys secret on the client is not a simple task and preferably, if you had a backend server, you could store them there. I wrote an [article](https://medium.com/proandroiddev/hide-your-api-keys-in-android-d4c52446d0bc) related to this subject, but like you mentioned, the reason for using secrets is to prevent them being exposed in version control.

Comment: The recommendation is to avoid security problems in development, not at run-time. It is recommended this way to keep the secrets out of the git repo (which may be public).